# Calling a class function from functions.php shortcode

Tags: wordpress, oop, shortcode

I thought this would work without question but I am missing something.

In my wordpress child functions.php:

```
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
    return My_Custom_Plugin_Public::display_custom_block();
}
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode');
```

display_custom_block() function:

```
    public static function display_custom_block() {
echo "hello world hello world";
    }
```

Unfortunately the page just cannot load this shortcode.  Am I not able to call a class function from within a shortcode?

Whole class:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die();
class My_Custom_Plugin_Public {

    private $plugin_name;

    private $version;

    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;

    }

    public static function display_custom_block() {
echo "hello world hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly are you calling this shortcode?

Comment: Added to my post.  The shortcode is added to my child theme functions.php

Comment: Can you add whole class code and how you are importing in functions.php

Comment: Added above.  Functions.php is default part of the theme and is working.  i.e. if I change the shortcode to 
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
 return '<p>Hello World!</p>';
}
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode'); it prints "Hello World!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all import the class file to functions.php as you said it's custom

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/YourCustomClass.php'); //Path of file
```

Then in your function you can call like this

```
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
    return My_Custom_Plugin_Public::display_custom_block();
} 
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode');
```

This should work

Comment: Hi, yes I agree.  The class is loaded from my main plugin file.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Did you enable `WP_DEBUG` to true in wp-config.php so that you can know the errors if any

Comment: Well how strange, thanks for checking, guess I need to re-look at everything.  I have my full plugin running on another site but I call My_Custom_Plugin_Public::display_custom_block(); directly in a template file.  This time I want to call it from a shortcode, that is all I am changing

Comment: Like i said try enabling WP_DEBUG and you can try out var_dump or print_r to debug and see if imported or not

Comment: I'm really sorry, such a silly mistake - I was calling the function from the wrong class!!!!

Comment: That's common with many of us . I'm glad you could solve it :)